Non-termination proof for all non-terminating algorithms?
Let Alg be the set of all algorithms (TM descriptions/ python code, etc.). This set is countably infinite.
In classical logic, the following statement is provable:
HaltOrNotHalt == ∀ alg ∈ Alg : Halts(alg) ∨ DoesNotHalt(alg)

where the predicates are defined as follows:
Halts(alg) == ∃step:Nat, RunFor(step, alg) = 'halt'
DoesNotHalt(alg) == ∀step:Nat, RunFor(step, alg) ≠ 'halt'

where RunFor is a (primitive recursive?) function which constitutes the operational semantics. Moreover, the reason why I don't define DoesNotHalt(alg) as ¬Halt(alg) is because I don't know whether the equivalence is true constructively..
In classical mathematics, HaltOrNotHalt is provable by LEM. In constructive mathematics, there is no proof for HaltOrNotHalt, as it solves the halting problem.
My question is follows:
Given an algorithm Alg that does not halt, can we always find a proof of DoesNotHalt(alg), and is the proof of DoesNotHalt(alg) constructive?
That is, while we know that there is no algorithm that can generate (halt/not_halt) proofs, can we have an infinite family of them?

If there was a proof of nonconvergence for every nonconvergent program/input, then there would be an algorithm to determine nonconvergence, since proofs are enumerable.  I'm not sure if this is what you are asking so I put it as a comment.

(Yes, DoesNotHalt is the negation of Halt constructively.)

I was just trying to compose a comment to explain why the question is ambiguous. The above comments from @DanielV and Naim, which answer the two different possible readings of the question, demonstrate the ambiguity: when you write "is the proof constructive", what proof are you referring to?

Re: "is the proof constructive", since DoesNotHalt(alg) is a negative proposition it is somewhat trivially constructive, e.g. you can use instances of LEM while proving it.

@NaïmFavier: you may be interested in my comment too.

@RobArthan there is no ambiguity. My first comment is not an answer to the question, only to "I don't know whether the equivalence is true constructively". My second comment is an answer to the second part of the question.

@NaïmFavier:  There is an ambiguity in the question: "is the proof constructive" could refer either to the putative proofs for each non-terminating algorithm that it does not terminate or to the proof of the universal statement quantified over all non-terminating algorithms. That's why you and Daniel were able to answer "no" and "yes" respectively. I was not saying that you made any ambiguous statements.

@RobArthan, I was talking about the putative proofs. I'll update the question

@RobArthan again, we gave different answers because we were answering different parts of the question, not different interpretations of the same question. There was no ambiguity in the original post. I did not clarify which question I was answering because I thought it would be obvious from the contents of my answer, but apparently not.

@DanielV, ah of course, I completely missed that! So there are algorithms for which we cannot have a proof that the don't terminate. The argument should go as follows:
We can enumerate all proofs and check whether they prove Halts(alg) or DoesNotHalt(alg). Having guaranteed assurance of this infinite family of proofs would mean that our enumeration would always halt. In other words, we solve the halting problem.
Now to check whether the above argument is constructive... ;)

There is an algorithm that looks for an inconsistency in ZFC. That cannot be proven not to halt in ZFC by Godel's second incompleteness theorem.

First, the equivalence $\text{DoesNotHalt}(\text{alg}) \iff \lnot\text{Halts}(\text{alg})$ is constructively true, as $\lnot\exists x, P(x) \iff \forall x, \lnot P(x)$ is a tautology of intuitionistic first-order logic. Proof: assume $\lnot \exists x, P(x)$, take $x$ and assume $P(x)$, deduce $\exists x, P(x)$ and obtain a contradiction with $\lnot \exists x, P(x)$; conversely, assume $\forall x, \lnot P(x)$, assume $\exists x, P(x)$, extract $x$ such that $P(x)$, and deduce a contradiction with $\lnot P(x)$ obtained from $\forall x, \lnot P(x)$. Or if you prefer to do it in a proof assistant, say, Coq:
Goal forall (T : Type) (P : T -> Prop),
    ~(exists x, P x) <-> (forall x, ~P x).
Proof.
  split.
  * intros H x H'. apply H. exists x. apply H'.
  * intros H H'. destruct H' as [x H']. apply H with (x := x).
    apply H'.
Qed.

Now to your main question: no, given a program that does not halt, you cannot always find a proof that it halts. Otherwise, you could in parallel run the program and search for a proof of its non-termination, and since one of the two would always terminate, you would have solved the halting problem. Since there is not always a classical proof of non-termination, there is a fortiori not always a constructive proof.

Another way to see that equivalence is as a form of dependent currying: using dependent type theory syntax, $(x : X) \times P(x) \to \bot$ is equivalent to $(x : X) \to P(x) \to \bot$.
